# How to mix different plantuml diagram type elements?

Tags: plantuml

I want to have deployment and sequence stuff in one and the same rendered plantuml picture. So I tried the following but it does not work, the rendering shows the sequence stuff for A, B and C as deployment.

How can I force rendering for "A->B" and "B->C" as sequence diagram stuff?

```
@startuml
file main.c
note right: I want to have description text here

A -> B : main()
note left : program\nentry function
B -> C : load()
note left : another important function
@enduml
```

Comment: allow_mixing does not work because it does not change to my desired type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to add your note later:

```
@startuml
title file main.c

A -> B : main()
note left : program\nentry function
B -> C : load()
note left : another important function

note right: I want to have description text here
@enduml
```

Result:

[image: generated output]

Answer (score 1):

For those that find this question who are trying to embed deployment diagrams within sequence diagrams, you can use `{{ }}`. As the main answer notes, the main diagram type is inferred (which is why the note had to be moved later), so after one does that, then you can embed deployment diagrams within. For example:

[image: PlantUML example]

```
@startuml

' Sequence diagram: https://plantuml.com/sequence-diagram
'   with embedded deployment diagrams using {{}} in notes: https://plantuml.com/deployment-diagram

title Test
hide footbox

' Tune this to get the box to cover all the groups
skinparam ParticipantPadding 50

mainframe Data Center 1

  box "Nodes" #FFFFFF

    participant Node1 #FFFFFF
    participant Node2 #FFFFFF
    participant Node3 #FFFFFF

    group Virtual Network 1

      group Cluster 1\n└ Application: MyApp

        ' The / on subsequent notes makes sure all notes are horizontally aligned

        rnote over Node1 #FFFFFF
        {{
          rectangle Server1
        }}
        endrnote
        
        / rnote over Node2 #FFFFFF
        {{
          rectangle Server2
        }}
        endrnote

        / rnote over Node3 #FFFFFF
        {{
          rectangle Server3
        }}
        endrnote

      end

    end

  end box

@enduml
```